# Selecting data from two tables using composite keys

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to select the users with their modules using the composite key. I can select on MySQL with SQL query but I'm new to entity framework and I'm having troubles figuring out. I appreciate any help that I can get. 
[image: db]

```
public class module
    {
        public int moduleid { get; set; }

        public string modulename { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("module_moduleid")]
        public ICollection<session> sessions { get; set; }

        public ICollection<user_has_module> usermodule { get; set; }

    }


    public class user_has_module
    {
        public String userid { get; set; }

        public int moduleid { get; set; }

        public user user { get; set; }

        public module module { get; set; }

    }

 public class user
    {
        [Key]
        public string userid { get; set; }

        public string userpw { get; set; }

        public string fullname { get; set; }

        public ICollection<user_has_module> usermodule { get; set; }

    }
```

This is my database context class.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<user> user { get; set; }

        public DbSet<module> module { get; set; }

        public DbSet<user_has_module> user_has_module { get; set; }



        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<user_has_module>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.userid, x.moduleid });

            modelBuilder.Entity<user_has_module>()
                .HasOne(x => x.user)
                .WithMany(y => y.usermodule)
                .HasForeignKey(y => y.userid);

            modelBuilder.Entity<user_has_module>()
                .HasOne(x => x.module)
                .WithMany(y => y.usermodule)
                .HasForeignKey(y => y.moduleid);

        }
    }
```

This is the query I'm trying to do in entity framework core.

```
From user
INNER JOIN user_has_module
ON user.userid = user_has_module.user_userid
INNER JOIN module
ON user_has_module.module_moduleid = module.moduleid;
```

Comment: This requires some more info: EF version, EF mapping code (if present) + your own attempt. The latter shows where you need help more specifically.

Comment: Pomelo EF core = v2.2.0
Microsoft.EFC = v2.2.6
I have updated the code above with my database context

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data from three tables using a composite key, you can be inspired by the following example :

```
var query = from o in db.Orders
from p in db.Products
join d in db.OrderDetails
    on new {o.OrderID, p.ProductID} equals new {d.OrderID, d.ProductID} into details
    from d in details
    select new {o.OrderID, p.ProductID, d.UnitPrice};
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: It's a bad idea to jump from SQL joins to LINQ joins. That's what navigation properties are for. Also, please always try to base an answer on the question's code.

Comment: error thrown is 'unknown column um.userid' in 'on clause'
this is what I tried:
https://i.imgur.com/53sb1cg.jpg

Comment: ExPIOiD, it's normal that you get this error because your table "user_has_module" doesn't contains column with name userid.

Comment: @YassineHAKKAM but what’s weird is the error appears at the foreach line. I’ll try changing um.user_userid and um.module_moduleid

Comment: @ExPlOiD, please take a look at your navigation properties and see how easy it is to query something like `user.usermodule.Select(um => um.module)`.